# Audio worker and AudioWorklet in web audio API

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web-audio-api

According to this [W3C Working Draft](https://www.w3.org/TR/webaudio/#the-scriptprocessornode-interface---deprecated), the ScriptProcessorNode is deprecated and will be replaced by AudioWorkerNode.
And Chrome recently has [AudioWorklet](https://www.chromestatus.com/features#audioworklet) implemented to replace ScriptProcessorNode.
Are those two APIs the same thing? Does Chrome just implement it with a different name?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it has just been renamed **AudioWorklet**, even [in the specs](https://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#AudioWorklet) probably to mark the distinction between this API and Web Worker, since this API is more like the [Worklets](https://drafts.css-houdini.org/worklets/) API proposed by CSS-WG.

They key points Worklets do differ to Workers are (according to [houdini page](https://drafts.css-houdini.org/worklets/#motivations))

> Worklets are similar to web workers however they:
>
> - Are thread-agnostic. That is, they are not defined to run on a particular thread. Rendering engines may run them wherever they choose.
> - Are able to have multiple duplicate instances of the global scope created for the purpose of parallelism.
> - Are not event API based. Instead classes are registered on the global scope, whose methods are to be invoked by the user agent.
> - Have a reduced API surface on the global scope.
> - Have a lifetime for the global scope which is defined by subsequent specifications or user agents. They aren’t tied to the lifetime of the document.
>
> As worklets have a relatively high overhead, they should be used sparingly. Due to this worklets are expected to be shared between separate scripts.